# Transformation of a random variable.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

[image]

In this transformation question, I managed to show the g(w) as given, yet I do not quite understand why the domain of the w is within plus and minus infinity. Shouldn't it be -1< w <1 as we are given that |u|< pi/2 ?

Answer (score 0):

$\tan$ gets arbitrarily large near $\pi/2$ and arbitrarily small near $-\pi/2$. See the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%28x%29+from+-pi%2F2+to+pi%2F2).